# curl php post request

Tags: php, curl, post, request

I have this code

```
POST /account/p_api/v1/account/authorization/assign HTTP/1.1
Host: exemple.com
Cookie: exemle-locale=en; 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 17
Origin: https://exemple.com
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Te: trailers
Connection: close

{"code":"herecode"}
```

I want to use curl and php to be able to send the request and add another code to "herecode"

I don't know how to do this

Comment: The [PHP curl docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) have examples.

Comment: This is not a coding service. Learn a bit and try yourself before ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Browser open the developer tools 
Go to the url in your Browser. 
Go to the "Network Tab" 
Right click the first request in the Network Tab 
Select copy => curl

Go to https://curlconverter.com/php/ 
Paste the "curl copy"  
And you have your PHP code.

There is a bug in their `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` you need to make your own header array.
Example header:

```
'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
```

Change to

```
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
```

**Firefox curl copy example:**

[image]

**Chrome  curl copy example:**

[image]

Paste to urlconverter:
This is a curl copy and paste for this page.  [curl php post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74605687/curl-php-post-request)

[image]